# What is the type of T?

Tags: c++, templates

In the code below:

```
template<typename T>
struct X {};

int main()
{
  X<int()> x; // what is the type of T ?
}
```

What is the type of T? I saw something like this in the `boost` sources.

Comment: I would be curious to know the purpose of using this 'syntax' (except to be used with `std::function`, `boost::function` or `boost::function_traits`)

Comment: But when we define 'int x = int()', the expression 'int()' is treated as value initialization $8.5/7. So it is tricky I guess

Comment: @chub: a type is expected there, not a value.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Consider the function `int func()`. It has a function type `int(void)`. It can be implicitly converted to pointer type as the C++ Standard says in 4.3/1, but it this case there's no need in such conversion, so `T` has the function type `int(void)`, not a pointer to it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I did. Though the output of code below is implementation specific, many times it gives a good hint into the type of T that we are dealing with.

```
template<typename T> 
struct X {
   X(){
      cout << typeid(T).name();
   }
}; 

int main() 
{ 
  X<int()> x; // what is the type of T ? 
  cout << typeid(int()).name() << endl;
}
```

The output on VC++ is

> int __cdecl(void)
>
> int __cdecl(void)

Answer (score 0):

The type of `T` is a function that takes no parameters and returns `int`, as in:

```
template<typename T>
struct X {};

int foo()
{
    return 42;
}
int main()
{
  X<int()> x; // what is the type of T ?
    typedef int(foo_ptr)();
    X<foo_ptr> x2;
    return 0;
}
```

`T` in `x` and `x2` are the same type.